# How Do I Build For A UAT Environment Using React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

According to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) you can have `development`, `test` and `production` envs.

The value of `NODE_ENV` is set automatically to **development** (when using `npm start`), **test** (when using `npm test`) or **production** (when using `npm build`). Thus, from the point of view of create-react-app, there are only three environments.

I need to change root rest api urls based on how I am deployed. 
e.g.

- development: `baseURL = 'http://localhost:3004';`
- test: `baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';`
- uat: `baseURL = 'http://uat.api.azure.com:8080';`
- production: `baseURL = 'http://my.cool.api.com';`

How do I configure a UAT environment for react if it only caters for dev, test and prod?

What would my javascript, package.json and build commands look like to switch these values automatically?

Comment: Use your own `APP_ENV` variable.

Comment: I also use [_dotenv-extended_](https://github.com/keithmorris/node-dotenv-extended) which works really well with different `.env` files, say `.env.uat`.

Comment: UAT is essentially staging no? UAT should be as similar as possible to production, where it exposes new features in the pipeline to be released to prod.

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, OP should use `NODE_ENV=production` in his UAT environment, doesn't help with his different configurations.

Comment: Yea, agreed :) Just pointing out that it should be production in the UAT env. There needs to be a separate environment variable beyond `NODE_ENV`. Or really you could just look at the domain you're running off of

Comment: @JohnRuddell _"look at the domain you're running off of"_ this would only work at runtime though, without the build time needs and benefits.

Comment: example of a build time need thats different between UAT and Prod?

Comment: @JohnRuddell any configuration that won't change after build time is better made at build time through something like the [_DefinePlugin_](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). Results in lighter built files without the configuration/code needed for every environment.

Comment: I get that, im just saying it should be production. that you probably dont need to have a plugin defined for UAT thats different from Prod, since they should be the same. That's how I always do it so its a UAT on the correct env so theres no regression between environmental changes. I can see how if you want to bundle code that only has one URL mapping could be useful though

Comment: @JohnRuddell it really depends on the project. Maybe UAT and PROD are rather similar, but DEV may have a lot of debug code and assertions that you don't want in any other build. So if you're using the DefinePlugin with `APP_ENV` to either `UAT` or `PROD`, the debug stuff will be stripped out completely from the build. Also, UAT and PROD might be uploaded to different servers, which is one huge reason not to use runtime check of the domain.

Comment: I agree dev and prod are different and thats where define plugin is good. I just am saying uat and prod are and should be the same. Uploaded to different servers is CI/CD deployment when you make a pull request + merge code into a branch. separate from the JS code

Comment: UAT and PROD are similar, but not identical, since they will be deployed to different servers and have different URLs.

Comment: @JohnRuddell our CD pipeline uses our env variable to upload to the right place, which is out of the built JS file, but still uses the same `APP_ENV`. Some tasks can be manually started, some pull requests or branches may be uploaded to multiple environments. It all comes down to the project needs, which we can't assume with OP's (or anyone's) project.

Comment: OP, note that Create-React-App is not React, it's an opinionated set of configurations that help building projects using React easily and quickly for most use-cases, but you can eject at anytime to customize the configuration files to your own needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [John Ruddell wrote in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189976/how-do-i-build-for-a-uat-environment-using-react/57191234#comment100890509_57189976), we should still use `NODE_ENV=production` in a staging environment to keep it as close as prod as possible. But that doesn't help with our problem here.

The reason why `NODE_ENV` can't be used reliably is that most Node modules use `NODE_ENV` to adjust and optimize with sane defaults, like Express, React, Next, etc. Next even completely changes its features depending on the commonly used values `development`, `test` and `production`.

So the solution is to create our own variable, and how to do that depends on the project we're working on.

## [Additional environments with Create React App (CRA)](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

The documentation says:

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to [avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252199527).

It was discussed in [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6905) where *Ian Schmitz* says:

> Instead you can create your own variable like `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL` which can have default values in dev and prod through the `.env` file if you'd like, then simply set that environment variable when building your app for staging like `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=... npm run build`.

A common package that I use is [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) so that anyone can run our npm scripts on any platform.

```
"scripts": {
  "build:uat": "cross-env REACT_APP_SERVER_URL='http://uat.api.azure.com:8080' npm run build"
```

## Any other JS project

If we're not bound to CRA, or have [ejected](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject), we can easily configure any number of environment configurations we'd like in a similar fashion.

Personally, I like [`dotenv-extended`](https://github.com/keithmorris/node-dotenv-extended) which offers validation for required variables and default values.

Similarly, in the `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:uat": "cross-env APP_ENV=UAT npm run build"
```

Then, in an entry point node script (one of the first script loaded, e.g. required in a babel config):

```
const dotEnv = require('dotenv-extended');

// Import environment values from a .env.* file
const envFile = dotEnv.load({
  path: `.env.${process.env.APP_ENV || 'local'}`,
  defaults: 'build/env/.env.defaults',
  schema: 'build/env/.env.schema',
  errorOnMissing: true,
  silent: false,
});
```

Then, as an example, a babel configuration file could use these like this:

```
const env = require('./build/env');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ['transform-define', env],
  ],
};
```

## Runtime configuration

John Ruddell also mentioned that one can detect at runtime the domain the app is running off of.

```
function getApiUrl() {
  const { href } = window.location;

  // UAT
  if (href.indexOf('https://my-uat-env.example.com') !== -1) {
    return 'http://uat.api.azure.com:8080';
  }

  // PROD
  if (href.indexOf('https://example.com') !== -1) {
    return 'http://my.cool.api.com';
  }

  // Defaults to local
  return 'http://localhost:3004';
}
```

This is quick and simple, works without changing the build/CI/CD pipeline at all. Though it has some downsides:

- All the configuration is "leaked" in the final build,
- It won't benefit from dead-code removal at minification time when using something like [`babel-plugin-transform-define`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/babel-plugin-transform-define) or [Webpack's `DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) resulting in a slightly bigger file size.
- Won't be available at compile time.
- Trickier if using Server-Side Rendering (though not impossible)

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple environments in a React.js application you can use this plugin
[env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) from NPM

And after that Create the three files as per your need.
For example if you want to setup dev, stag and prod environments you can write your commands like this.

```
"start:dev": "env-cmd -f dev.env npm start", // dev env
"build:beta": "env-cmd -f stag.env npm run build", // beta env
"build": "react-scripts build", // prod env using .env file
```